# how do i get my c# code to recognize "ö"?

Tags: c#, utf-8

how do i get my c# code to recognize "ö"?

The output of the query is nice and formatted all special characters are visible, but in codebehind, i cannot use them for sorting.

example:

```
if (link.Contains("teborg"))
{
    CountRss++;
    Response.Write("<p class='RssCont'><a href='" + link + "' target='new'><b>" + title + "</b></a><br/>");
    Response.Write(description + "</p>");
}
```

will give several results with "Göteborg" in title but:

```
if (link.Contains("Göteborg"))
{
    CountRss++;
    Response.Write("<p class='RssCont'><a href='" + link + "' target='new'><b>" + title + "</b></a><br/>");
    Response.Write(description + "</p>");
}
```

will give no results at all.

Comment: Not addressing your actual question, but `if (link.Contains("teborg"))` does the same thing and is more readable: the English equivalent is "if the link contains "teborg", then ..."

Comment: Are you certain that the `link` string contains `Göteborg` and not `göteborg`? String comparisons using `Contains` are case sensitive. Also, a nit pick - no need to have the `== true`, as `Contains` already returns a boolean.

Comment: Note: C# uses UTF16 internally, so `ö` gets recognized - this is not the real issue you are facing.

Comment: Can you give your exact two strings which show this behavior? There are different representations for `ö`: once as a single codepoint, and once as `o` + combining `¨`.

Comment: On a side note, you probably should be checking against "Goteborg" anyway and sanitizing keywords, since I guess many people and automated tools would drop the accentuation anyhow.

Comment: @Thomas - Please explain this? Why should this be done? Not everyone lives in ASCII land...

Comment: @Oded Because with your method, the people who do live in ASCII land will be SOL whereas by sanitizing, it works with everyone at the cost of possible confusion due to ambiguous characters, which will be pretty rare. Of course, it depends on your particular situation, but as the OP gave no context I added it as a generic "side note".

Comment: @Thomas - My method? I simply asked for your rationale.

Comment: @Oded Ah, "my method" as in "the method opposite to the one I suggest", sorry about that. My rationale is that *in general*, sanitizing input is the best way to go, and increases robustness of the software.

Comment: Maybe your link contains `G%c3%b6teborg`

Comment: It's a web application, the people who live in ASCII-land don't have high-tech stuff like the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfectly sensible and good as code, the issue is with data. There are four general possibilities here.

The first is encoding issues, but I doubt this is the case as you say that it's rendering okay, so I'd highly doubt that's the issue or you'd have problems there too.

The second is a conflict between composed `ö` and `ö` formed from a `o` followed with combining-diaresis. This is unlikely, but putting the string into NFC with `link.Normalize()` will catch that.

The third is that since it's a URI it might be in URI rather than IURI form. So it'll be `G%c3%b6teborg` (indeed, it could be `G%C3%b6teborg`, `G%c3%B6teborg` or `G%C3%B6teborg`). Unescape the string with `Uri.UnescapeDataString(link)` or any of the various methods for this. This is the one I'd bet on.

The fourth is that it could be XML escaped (since it's from RSS to judge from the names used), in which case `HtmlDecode` should sort that out as barring a DTD defining other entities, the encoding for HTML is a superset of that for XML. However, this is only possible if you are parsing the RSS with text-based rather than XML-based methods in which case you've got bigger problems. If you're using XmlReader or XmlDocument or any other XML based class, this decoding will have been done for you already if necessary, so that's not the issue.

So the third is by far seeming the most likely, and `Uri.UnescapeDataString(link)` seems the most promising.

You might want a less precise check that case-sensitive exact char for char. Other methods will let you match `göteborg` and `GÖTEBORG` too. There are also some that would e.g. match `goeteborg` (it's common to transliterate `ö` to `oe` in English - this is more often done with German than Swedish but it might still be done). (Matching e.g. the English `Gothenburg` or the Danish `Gøteborg` is a much more involved matter).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll return here when sorted out =)

Answer (score 0):

If your code renders link correctly it should be encoded and as result will not contain non-ASCII characters.

Depending on position of the word in the url you may need to search for different text to find match.

Note that using proper Uri class to deal with url will make life easier. Also make sure you have correctly encoded link to avoid script injection attacks on your page.